# Movie where a woman paints portraits of a man she sees in her dreams

Tags: identify-this-movie

I vaguely recall seeing a particular scene from a movie or possibly a trailer. A man enters a room where a woman is painting portraits of him. She explains to him that even though she has never met him before, she consistently sees this man in her dreams. I believe the implication is that she and this man were once close, but that she has somehow lost her memory of him. Nevertheless, she retains some subconscious memory of him that seems to manifest itself in her dreams. I do not recall if he is aware of who she is on the other hand.

I want to say I saw this clip in the mid-2000's or so. That's about all of the details I can scrounge up. I don't remember the actor or actress involved in the scene.

Comment: Any chance you remember what language it was in? (Maybe even accents?) Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sounds like the romantic comedy from 2004, "50 First Dates".

> Henry Roth (Adam Sandler) is a man afraid of commitment up until he meets the beautiful Lucy (Drew Barrymore). They hit it off and Henry think he's finally found the girl of his dreams, until he discovers she has short-term memory loss and forgets him the very next day.

In [this trailer](https://youtu.be/iYU7ltkHYXM) you can see a scene that you described.

Comment: Saw this movie recently, can recommend!

Comment: Bur Lucy never painted pictures anywhere in the movie.

Comment: @CodeNewbie She does at one point when she leaves her home

Comment: @CodeNewbie she painted a wall every single day, part of their routine was blanking it out! Plus when she went off to the carehome she painted pics of Henry just at the OP describes.

Comment: It was near the end of the movie.

Comment: Saw this movie back when it came out, would *not* recommend.  Adam Sandler and Drew Barrymore were a lot better together in *The Wedding Singer*.

Comment: 50 First Dates is an at times awkward mix of a generally serious and sentimental story line with silly, puerile side shows. I have seen people cringe. A typical Sandler, you could say. Perhaps neither part would be bearable without the other. Overall, I liked it. Watched it a couple times over the years, and each time I get sentimental all over again ;-). Drew Barrymore is very sweet. It's a fairy tale.

Comment: That's the exact moment I was looking for. The part where she goes to the care home and starts to paint pictures of Adam Sandler. Thanks!

Comment: @Neuty I watched this movie only once, but scene that you described immediately reminded me of him. I'm glad that I could help... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe too early and also not exactly matching, but this reminds me of Star Trek: The Next Generation Episode [Haven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haven_%28Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation%29) (Se1, Ep.11).

> Wyatt has had numerous dreams of another woman with whom he has fallen in love, and had initially believed her to be Troi communicating telepathically with him.
>
> Wyatt recognizes one of the Tarellians, Ariana (Danitza Kingsley), from his dreams, and she too recognizes Wyatt.

He always draws the woman he sees in his dreams and regonizes here when they met them the first time. When he is first time in her room on their ship, he sees that she also has made several drawings of him

could not find a screenshot of this, but you can see it in this trailer at 0:19

Answer (score 0):

It could be Crying Freeman (1995). Emu O'Hara is an artist who accidentally sees the face of an assassin. She paints a picture of him knowing that he will have to come to kill her.

I believe the picture painting part was a key part of one of the trailers.